# Gatling all request failed with Network is unreachable

Tags: gatling

I use the currently latest version 2.0.0.-M3a of Gatling under Debian Wheezy, this is my first test of this tool. All the scenario failed with the following errors :

```
15:36:41.929 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandler - Request 'request_1' failed: Network is unreachable to http://localhost/
15:36:41.929 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'request_1' failed : Network is unreachable to http://localhost/
15:36:42.028 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandler - Request 'request_2' failed: Network is unreachable to http://localhost/public/login.html
15:36:42.029 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'request_2' failed : Network is unreachable to http://localhost/public/login.html
```

I tried other the sample scenario and it's the same, I checked my network and it works well, to localhost or other host.
May be some java libs are missing, I didn't find anywhere the java package list requirements for Debian.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have something listening on port 80 on localhost?
Have you tried specifying the port explicitly?